# Printing unicode string not correct

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I use PyPDF2 to read a pdf file but get a unicode string.

I don't know what's the encoding, then try to dump first 8 chars to hex:

```
0000  005b 00d7 00c1 00e8 00d4 00c5 00d5        [......
```

What's these bytes means? is it utf-16be/le?

I try below code but output is wrong:

```
print outStr.encode('utf-16be').decode('utf-16')
嬀휀섀퐀씀픀
```

If print directly, python will report error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am following the instruction from [How To Extract Text From Pdf In Python](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-in-python/)

Code section as below:

```
import PyPDF2
import textract
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

FILTER = ''.join([(len(repr(chr(x))) == 3) and chr(x) or '.' for x in range(256)])
def dumpUnicodeString(src, length=8):
    result = []
    for i in xrange(0, len(src), length):
       unichars = src[i:i+length]
       hex = ' '.join(["%04x" % ord(x) for x in unichars])
       printable = ''.join(["%s" % ((ord(x) <= 127 and FILTER[ord(x)]) or '.') for x in unichars])
       result.append("%04x  %-*s  %s\n" % (i*2, length*5, hex, printable))
    return ''.join(result)

def extractPdfText(filePath=''):
    fileObject = open(filePath, 'rb')
    pdfFileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fileObject)
    totalPageNumber = pdfFileReader.numPages

    currentPageNumber = 0
    text = ''
    while(currentPageNumber < totalPageNumber ):
        pdfPage = pdfFileReader.getPage(currentPageNumber)
        text = text + pdfPage.extractText()
        currentPageNumber += 1

    if(text == ''):
        text = textract.process(filePath, method='tesseract', encoding='utf-8')       
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    pdfFilePath = 'a.pdf'
    pdfText = extractPdfText(pdfFilePath)
    #pdfText = pdfText[:7]
    print dumpUnicodeString(pdfText)
    print pdfText
```

Comment: Are you 100% that the text from that PDF is actually copy-able? (Because it is not a fact that you *always can*.)

Comment: Yes, I can open the pdf and copy test from it.

Comment: It could be that the shell you're running under doesn't support the pringting of Unicode. This is true of the Windows command-line console `cmd`, I believe.

Comment: @martineau I am using macosx, and when try to save it to file, error report also "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-7: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: What are the characters displayed in the PDF that you are trying to copy

Comment: lucky1928: Saving it to a file is a completely different issue from printing it.

Comment: Like @JGNI asked, what would the correct output from `print` look like?

Comment: @matineau If print directly, error reported "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-7: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: @JGNI's suggestion to manually copy them from the PDF itself (and paste them into your question) might avoid that.

Comment: It's unlikely you need to call `encode`, as it already appears to be encoded text.

Comment: How exactly are you getting that unicode string from PyPDF2?

Comment: @martineau I just reading a post! updated to question for reference!

Comment: With Python 2,  the `extractText()` method In PyPDF2 returns a `unicode` object (a sequence of Unicode code units). Your code snippet attempts to convert that to UTF-16, however the terminal you're using appears to only support printing of ASCII characters. I'm not familiar with macosx, but there's probably some way to configure the terminal being used so it supports displaying UTF text.